# Shared Preference saving the checkbox action

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I was able to store the value of checkbox using shared preference but I was not able to save the *action* its meant to do.The action what i need is when checkbox is checked a button should display,if checkbox is unchecked button should not display(hiding/showing button is done in different activity). So what I did was i passed the value `isCheckedValue = isChecked;`  under if/else condition

```
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    checkBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("checked",false));

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        isCheckedValue = isChecked;
        editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
        editor.apply();

            if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                isCheckedValue = isChecked;
                editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor.apply();
            }else{
                editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });
```

if chkbox is checked the value will pass using intent in `onBubbleClick`  using the boolean passing data `in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );` you could notice it in below bunch of code

```
    private void addNewBubble() {
        BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
                in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
        bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
    }
```

**How it works:** At the very beginning the button is not displayed until the checkbox is clicked, the button gets displayed once the checkbox is checked and never gets hidden even after unchecked the checkbox.
**How it's meant to work** The button should display if the checkbox is checked and button should hide if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Try using `.commit()` instead of `.apply()`, I believe `.commit` is synchronous where the other runs in the background.

Comment: @CookieMonster it didn't really help in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if-else block, you aren't really updating the value of `isCheckedValue` in `false` condition. So, that needs to be fixed. I also refactored your code a bit. Try the following:

```
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

checkBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("checked",false));

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        isCheckedValue = isChecked;
        editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
        editor.apply();
    } 
});
```

Comment: @GladwinJames the above code should work just fine. You don't need the if-else block inside `onCheckedChanged`

Comment: So the code you have provide would also remember the checkbox value(check/uncheck)? but how can you xplain please(I'm just a beginner) the explanation would really help.

Comment: Yeah, the line `isCheckedValue = isChecked;` will remember so that we can pass the value to next activity. and the couple of lines after that will write the value to our `SharedPreference`...try it

Comment: Can you please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060962/checkbox-passing-of-action-on-reopening-of-the-app/39061061#39061061) ?