# Checkbox passing of action on reopening of the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have stored the checkbox value(check/uncheck) using shared preference,but I face problem while passing the action of checkbox on/after closing and reopening the app.
*Explantion*: A button in different actvity hides/shows on clicking the checkbox(i.e check=shows & uncheck= hides) working correctly.
 when I close the app and reopen the checkbox stays checked but button is not appearing

checkbox code saved using shared preference

```
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        checkBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("checked",false));

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                isCheckedValue = isChecked;
                editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

    }
```

I tried to implement onStart() for passing data by providing if-else condition

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        super.onStart();
        if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
            editor.apply();
        }else{
            editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```

This is where i am passing the data once the checkbox is checked

```
@Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
                in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
                startActivity(in);

            }
```

Comment: I'm confused about your flow a bit. Lets say you have two activities: `Activity1` [A1] (with checkbox) and `Activity2` [A2] (with button). You are able to pass the proper value from "A1 to A2". When you say you put the app to the background. What exactly is the flow after that?

Comment: @Shaishav I am not putting the app in background I'm completely closing the app and starting again, when i start the app again the checbox(add_fb) is checked but the button in different activity which needs to display is not showing
(I could brief the process in chat but i dont no how to start one)

Comment: Put: `isCheckedValue  = preferences.getBoolean("checked",false); checkBox.setChecked(isCheckedValue);` right where you call checkBox.setChecked() currently.

Comment: dude how? just tell me how should I learn to become like you in android development please where should i start my basics can you mail me if i give you my mail id huh? please do reply @Shaishav

Comment: haha ..I still needs to learn SO much..!...Anyway I'd suggest, just pay attention to lifecycle events and align your app 'flow' accordingly, learn to use debug breakpoints wisely and prefer docs/books over video tuts... you'll get good with time...

Comment: @Shaishav where do I start with should I start with java(basics I know) so should I get in deeper and learn more or should I go directly to android.developers and learn ..??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending 'isCheckedValue' in 'onBubbleClickMethod' 
try this -

in.putExtra("yourBoolName",preferences.getBoolean("checked",false));